# Value defined in one function not available in another

Tags: python, function, return, global, variable-assignment

Alright, so this is my first post. I have searched through here trying to find any questions for reference if I missed it I apologize.

So my daughter and I are writing a game together. I have been working on some of the foundation programming while she does the creative stuff. 
I have a function where the user picks a "class" that assigns base values for certain aspects and returns them as a variable. Following other posts I first tried using **return** function but that didn't work so I tried **global** function. That allows the program to use the variable to simply print it outside the function, but when another function tries to use the variable it comes up as not variable referenced before assignment.

```
     import random
     import time
     #these were another attempt at finding a way to make the classes
     #available to other functions
     combat = 0
     strength = 0 
     agility = 0
     magic = 0
     intelligence = 0
     def chose_class():
         #I tried return "each characteristic" at the end, but it wouldn't 
         #even print out the returned value
         global strength
         global combat
         global agility
         global magic
         global intelligence
         health = 10
         print("Chose your class:")
         print("Warrior: 1")
         print("Wizard: 2")
         print("Philosopher: 3")
         print("Thief: 4")
         print("Help: 5")
         dog1 = int(input(":"))
         if dog1 ==1:
             strength = 7
             combat = 7
             agility = 5
             stealth = 3
             magic = 1
             intelligence = 1
         elif dog1 == 2:
             strength = 3
             combat = 1
             agility = 3
             stealth = 3
             magic = 8
             intelligence = 6
         elif dog1 == 3: 
             strength = 3
             combat = 1
             agility = 3
             stealth = 3
             magic = 2
             intelligence = 8
         elif dog1 == 4:
             strength = 2
             combat = 4
             agility = 6
             stealth = 8 
             magic = 1
             intelligence = 6
         elif dog1 == 5:
             print("Warrior Dog:")
             print("    Warrior Dogs possess great strength and combat                                    ability")
             print("    they have medium agility, but low stealth, magic and")
             print("    intelligence.")
             print("\n"*2)
             print("Wizard Dog:")
             print("    Wizard Dogs have low strength, combat, and agility,")
             print("    they have medium stealth and high magic capabilities.")
             print("\n"*2)
             print("Philosopher Dog:")
             print("    Philosopher Dogs are highly intelligent, while they")
             print("    have low strength, they have medium combat ability.")
             print("    Their agility, stealth, and magic start low but can")
             print(" rapidly improve by finding hidden objects on quests.")  
             print("\n"*2)
             print("Thief Dogs")
             print("    Thief Dogs have high agility and stealth, as well as")
             print("    average intelligence and combat. They have low combat,")
             print("    magic, and strength.")
         else:
             chose_class()
     def room17():
         print("**Description**")
         print("Do you want to fight the cat guard or sneak past it?")
         print("Fight: 1")
         print("Sneak Past: 2")
         choice17 = str(input(":"))
         if "1" in choice17:
             fight17 = random.randint(0,5)
             combat17 = combat * fight17
             if combat17 <= 20:
                 print("You were successful")
                 combat = combat + 1
             else:
                 print("You lost the fight and had to retreat")
                 health = health - 1
                 room1()
         else:
             sneak17 = random.randint(0,5)
             stealth17 = sneak17 * stealth
             if stealth17 <= 20:
                 print("You snuck past the guard")
                 stealth = stealth + 1
             else:
                 print("The guard caught you, he attacks and you have to retreat")
                 health = health - 2
                 stealth = stealth - 1
                 room1()
     chose_class()
     # this was just to see if the value was returned
     print("Combat:", combat)
     # I'm jumping to the first combat event to try to test the program
     room17()
```

Okay, so that should be enough of what I have to demonstrate the issue. I'm completely self taught so I'm sure there are tons of stylistic issues, which I'm perfectly happy to get help with. But if anyone can help with why the variable "combat" is returned from "def chose_class()" to the print command but then not assigned in the "def room17()" I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In `chose_class`, you have `global combat`. In `room17`, you don't (that's the problem). Add the global definition (and any other var that you use the same way), and you'll be fine.

Comment: That did the job. Thank you.

Comment: I have seen a lot of people complaining about using global as a style choice. If I used return in "chose_class" how would I match it in "room17"?

Comment: If you return it from `choose_class` either you must call `choose_class` in `room17`, either pass it as an argument to `room17`.

Comment: The issue of global variables isn't one merely of style, but of fundamental program organization. Suffice it to say, the accumulated experience of over half a century of programming has lead to the realization that a program that relies on changeable global state leads to subtle, hard to find bugs, and makes programs more difficult to reason about. For this sort of educational project it's fine. But maybe your next exercise would be converting your program to use functions that take arguments and return values and leave only global constants.